# Проблема сегментации изображения. image thresholding problem, image segmentation

Tags: python, matlab, сегментация

Проблема заключается в том, что при проведение thresholding сегментации изображения, никак не получается разделить небо и фон, к небу постоянно добавляется ствол дерева, от которого отсвечивает солнечный свет. Пробовал несколько методов, например разделение по RGB каналам, но это не помогло. Если у кого, пожалуйста, опыт или совет, как можно провести сегментация данных типов изображений более точно?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]